# What does this phrase mean? "Trust me to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Trust me to open my mouth, now everybody knows Trust me, now I've let
>   you down

*(Squeeze - Trust Me To Open My Mouth Lyrics)*

I have found this phrase

> "trust me to get haunted by the flakiest ghost in the world",

but I cannot understand its meaning and I googled it and found the song by Squeeze. Do they have the same meaning?

***Thank you for help!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a somewhat idiomatic usage. Literally, *[You can] **trust me to** [do something stupid*, is effectively a rueful admission that it's *typical* of me to do stupid things (so it's no surprise that I just did it again).

It's not only used when the *speaker* is calling attention to his own (typical) action, so...

> [*"Trust you to do something stupid!"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22trust%20you%20to%20do%20something%20stupid%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...is an idiomatic colloquial usage meaning *You've just done something stupid, which is typical of you.*

Also note that the "typical" action needn't always be an obviously *bad* thing. I can't easily track down a written instance, but...

> *"Trust John to throw a great party!"*

...could reasonably be said *admiringly* by a guest if John's party is obviously going really well, and everyone (or at least, *the speaker*) knows perfectly well that John's parties are *always* great fun).

I should perhaps point out that in every context I can imagine, the *object* of the verb *(you, John)* is always heavily ***stressed*** in speech.